# Gensim most_similar() with Fasttext word vectors return useless/meaningless words

Tags: gensim, fasttext

I'm using Gensim with [Fasttext Word vectors](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html) for return similar words.

This is my code:

```
import gensim

model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('cc.it.300.vec')

words = model.most_similar(positive=['sole'],topn=10)

print(words)
```

This will return:

```
[('sole.', 0.6860659122467041), ('sole.Ma', 0.6750558614730835), ('sole.Il', 0.6727924942970276), ('sole.E', 0.6680260896682739), ('sole.A', 0.6419174075126648), ('sole.È', 0.6401025652885437), ('splende', 0.6336565613746643), ('sole.La', 0.6049465537071228), ('sole.I', 0.5922051668167114), ('sole.Un', 0.5904430150985718)]
```

The problem is that "sole" ("sun", in english) return a series of words with a dot in it (like sole., sole.Ma, ecc...). Where is the problem? Why most_similar return this meaningless word?

**EDIT**

I tried with [english word vector](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html) and the word "sun" return this:

```
[('sunlight', 0.6970556974411011), ('sunshine', 0.6911839246749878), ('sun.', 0.6835992336273193), ('sun-', 0.6780728101730347), ('suns', 0.6730450391769409), ('moon', 0.6499731540679932), ('solar', 0.6437565088272095), ('rays', 0.6423950791358948), ('shade', 0.6366724371910095), ('sunrays', 0.6306195259094238)]
```

Is it impossible to reproduce results like relatedwords.org?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the bigger question is: why does the Facebook FastText `cc.it.300.vec` model include so many meaningless words? (I haven't noticed that before – is there any chance you've downloaded a peculiar model that has decorated words with extra analytical markup?)

To gain the unique benefits of FastText – including the ability to synthesize plausible (better-than-nothing) vectors for out-of-vocabulary words – you may not want to use the general `load_word2vec_format()` on the plain-text `.vec` file, but rather a Facebook-FastText specific load method on the `.bin` file. See:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors

(I'm not sure that will help with these results, but if choosing to use FastText, you may be interesting it using it "fully".)

Finally, given the source of this training – common-crawl text from the open web, which may contain lots of typos/junk – these might be legimate word-like tokens, essentially typos of `sole`, that appear often enough in the training data to get word-vectors. (And because they really are typo-synonyms for 'sole', they're not necessarily bad results for all purposes, just for your desired purpose of only seeing "real-ish" words.)

You might find it helpful to try using the `restrict_vocab` argument of `most_similar()`, to only receive results from the leading (most-frequent) part of all known word-vectors. For example, to only get results from among the top 50000 words:

```
words = model.most_similar(positive=['sole'], topn=10, restrict_vocab=50000)
```

Picking the right value for `restrict_vocab` might help in practice to leave out long-tail 'junk' words, while still providing the real/common similar words you seek.

Comment: restrict_vocab=50000 resolve the problem, thank you!

Comment: the suggestion on restrict_vocab is really great!