# What is the input format of fastText and why does my model doesn't give me a meaningful similar output?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, sentiment-analysis, fasttext, sentence-similarity

My goal is to find similarities between a word and a document. For example, I want to find the similarity between "new" and a document, for simplicity, say "Hello World!".

I used word2vec from gensim, but the problem is it does not find the similarity for an unseen word. Thus, I tried to use fastText from gensim as it can find similarity for words that are out of vocabulary.

Here is a sample of my document data:

```
[['This', 'is', 'the', 'only', 'rule', 'of', 'our', 'household'],
 ['If',
  'you',
  'feel',
  'a',
  'presence',
  'standing',
  'over',
  'you',
  'while',
  'you',
  'sleep',
  'do'],
 ['NOT', 'open', 'your', 'eyes'],
 ['Ignore', 'it', 'and', 'try', 'to', 'fall', 'asleep'],
 ['This',
  'may',
  'sound',
  'a',
  'bit',
  'like',
  'the',
  'show',
  'Bird',
  'Box',
  'from',
  'Netflix']]
```

I simply train data like this:

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText

model = FastText(sentences_cleaned)
```

Consequently, I want to find the similarity between say, "rule" and this document.

`model.wv.most_similar("rule")`

However, fastText gives me this:

```
[('the', 0.1334390938282013),
 ('they', 0.12790171802043915),
 ('in', 0.12731242179870605),
 ('not', 0.12656228244304657),
 ('and', 0.11071767657995224),
 ('of', 0.08563747256994247),
 ('I', 0.06609072536230087),
 ('that', 0.05195673555135727),
 ('The', 0.002402491867542267),
 ('my', -0.009009800851345062)]
```

Obviously, it must have "rule" as the top similarity since the word "rule" appears in the first sentence of the document. I also tried stemming/lemmatization, but it doesn't work either.

Was my input format correct? I've seen lots of documents are using .cor or .bin format and I don't know what are those.

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "document", since as gojomo mentions you don't show yourself training any documents. However, one other issue in your code is that `most_similar` takes a **list** of words. Try `most_similar(["rule"])` and you should get words that are similar to "rule" at least.

Comment: Check this similar question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55872853/gensim-most-similar-with-fasttext-word-vectors-return-useless-meaningless-word) . It is suggested to get most similar like this : words = model.most_similar(positive=['rule'], topn=10, restrict_vocab=50000)

Answer (score 1):

`model.wv.most_similar('rule')` asks for that's model's set-of-word-vectors (`.wv`) to return the words most-similar to `'rule'`. That is, you've provided neither any document (multiple words) as a query, nor is there any way for the `FastText` model to return either a document itself, or a name of any documents. Only words, as it has done.

While FastText trains on texts – lists of word-tokens – it only models words/subwords. So it's unclear what you expected instead: the answer is of the proper form.

Those don't look like words very-much like `'rule'`, but you'll only get good results from `FastText` (and similar word2vec-algorithms) if you train them with lots of varied data showing many subtly-contrasting realistic uses of the relevant words.

How many texts, with how many words, are in your `sentences_cleaned` data? (How many uses of `'rule'` and related words?)

In any real `FastText`/`Word2Vec`/etc model, trained with  asequate data/parameters, no single sentence (like your 1st sentence) can tell you much about what the results "should" be. That only emerged from the full rich dataset.

Comment: Yeah you are right. `sentences_cleaned` is just a small paragraph. I am using it to try out fasttext. I have a relatively large dataset contains a column of paragraphs and corresponding scores. I am just not very clear about what is the input format of this model. I am thinking if I can get this model to work in a sense of maybe the maximum similarity of tokens in a paragraph and several words to construct a feature set.

Comment: It can be sensible to test mere execution & lack-of-format errors with toy-sized datasets. And, your `list` of `list of str` is acceptable input for the model. (Though, with larger training data, you often want to use a re-iterable sequence where each item is a `list of str`, to stream data from disk instead of creating a giant `list` in RAM, as if often demonstrated in Gensim intro docs/tutorials, as with the `LineSentence` utility class for iterating over a large text file.)

Comment: But because expected/useful/describable qualities of word-vectors only emerge with large/varied training data, it's not useful to dig through specifics of models on toy-sized data for expected behavior. Only with plentiful realistic training data should you start to worry if the results of any particular `most_similar()` results-list make sense.